# Is it possible to generate swagger.json with out deploying the application?

Tags: json, jax-rs, swagger, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

I'm a beginner in swagger and by following the documentation I'm able to generate swagger.json (swagger definition in json schema format) and also able to view that in swagger-ui.

But currently I'm able to access my json schema file only after deploying my application(It is getting generated under the base path I have given in web.xml).

Is there anyway to get it without deploying the application? Because each time when I want to re-check the documentation after a change has done, I have to deploy my application. It would be better if we have any offline method.

Thanks.

Comment: In this scenario, 'testing' means you call the apis with the swagger-ui right? or any other meaning?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34984820/5934435

Comment: @SupunWijerathne : No i Just want to see my documentation.. (Later i can remove that Tryout option too.)

Comment: You just want to change the annotations and check the documentation right?

Comment: Yes @SupunWijerathne