# Share documentation of web api offline

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger, documentation

I have a web API. The client of my API cannot consume it with the url now due to infra issue. I would like to share a documemnt similar to swagger with the client so that they can use it as reference for their development.

Any suggestions to do this. I have Swashbucke integrated in wbe api.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50137466/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Downloaded the json from Swagger and shared it with the client